# JQuery.getJSON not alerting json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I currently running in localhost:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/call", function(json) {
  alert(json.something);
});
```

`http://localhost/call` returns `{something:1}`, yet nothing is alerted.

Comment: Your JSON response seems to be invalid. And `as of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: You should use the methods the server-side language provides to convert data structures to JSON instead of building it on your own. *edit:* http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{something:1}
```

Isnt a valid [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string, however

```
{"something":1}
```

is.

If you replace your call with

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/call',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(){},
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
         //you should get a parse error and end up here
    }
});
```

you should end up in the `error` callback.

In your php file:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$arr = array('something' => 1, 'somethingelse' => 2);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Doggonit, I knew it would be something like this.

Comment: @Babiker Hehe, we all make misstakes ;) What serverside language are you using?

Comment: @Babiker Then I would recommend the `json_encode()` function(http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Don't generate JSON "manually", it will only make life hard ;)

Comment: Surething, Just trying to sandpaper the rust off, haven't done any coding for a while and I'm doing some quick tests :)

Comment: @Babiker I've added some php code that might be useful. Haven't tried it though. And its been a while since I used php, but hopefully itll help :)